# How to add a Timestamp in Firestore with Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a timestamp field in an Android client with Firebase Firestore.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ServerTimestamp):

> Annotation used to mark a Date field to be populated with a server
>   timestamp. If a POJO being written contains null for a
>   @ServerTimestamp-annotated field, it will be replaced with a
>   server-generated timestamp.

But when I try it:

```
@ServerTimestamp
Date serverTime = null; // I tried both java.util.Date and java.sql.Date

//...

Map<String, Object> msg = new HashMap<>();
// ... more data
msg.put("timestamp", serverTime);
```

On the Cloud Firestore database this field is always `null`.

Comment: You're annotating a local variable, not a POJO field.  There is a big difference between the two.

Comment: With that anotation you are telling Firestore convertion that when the POJO is used the field with that equivalent name in the Store DB must be transformed from Firestore tiemstamp to date. You have to set the timestamp first. Firestore wont set the Timestamp automatically because Firestore doesn't know when the timestamp should be set, on creation? on update? on an specific field write? Look at the Ali answer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That is not the correct way of how to add the time and date to a Cloud Firestore database. The best practice is to have a model class in which you can add a date field of type `Date` together with an annotation. This is how your model class should look like:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class YourModelClass {
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date date;

    YourModelClass() {}

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

When you create on object of `YourModelClass` class, there is no need to set the date. Firebase servers will read your `date` field, as it is a `ServerTimestamp` (see the annotation), and it will populate that field with the server timestamp accordingly.

Another approach would be to use [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#serverTimestamp()) method like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("date", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
docRef.update(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {/* ... */}
```

Comment: Is there everything alright? Can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Great! Now it's working, Effectively, writing this field in a pojo class does the trick. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting null 
        Logger.info("Date", new YourModelClass().getDate() + "");

Comment: Add a new question that cotains a mcve so me and other user can help you too.

Comment: Nothing i have done i just copied above model and printed the date on log
Like 
Log.d("Date",new YourModelClass().getDate()+"") but i am getting null

Comment: @RajKumar You say you have done nothing but still not working. That;s why I said to post a new question so we can take a closer look.

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran Please post another fresh question containing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Comment: am using above model class  but my date field is always null

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran Without seeing your code, I cannot help you at all. So please add another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51358563/5498065 @AlexMamo please take a look

Comment: can you help me @AlexMamo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124994/how-to-fetch-documents-from-one-month-old-only-firestore/61125159#61125159   will upvote

Answer (score 6):

use [`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#serverTimestamp()) get server timestamp

```
Map<String, Object> msg = new HashMap<>();
msg.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
```

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem, and I found this at my catlog and solved my problem

```
firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                .build();
firebaseFirestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,

I was getting the exception `...has type java.sql.Timestamp, got java.util.Date ...`, so I just replace the type from `Timestamp` to `Date` ( from `java.util.Date`) and worked fine.