# Ordering Firestore documents in descending order in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-gridview

I want to order Firestore documents in descending order according to the timestamp they have uploaded. I mean when I upload a new photo it should appear on the top of the image grid that I have made. Here I used orderBy and I passed true for the parameter descending (bottom of the code in the get images method). by default it is false and then the image grid is ordering ascending fine. When I upload a new image it works fine with ascending order. But when I set true to parameter descending inside the orderBy it is not working. It makes a duplicate image of previously uploaded one (see the image link below). But when I restart the app it is ordered descending. ascending is updating realtime but descending is not. We just only have to change the boolean value of descending parameter to get either ascending order or descending order. I would be grateful if someone can help me with this issue. Here is my code,

```
class DatabaseService {

  final String uid;

  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  // collection reference
  final CollectionReference imageCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('images');

  // creating new document for a image user and updating existing image data
  Future updateImageData(String location, String url) async{
    return await imageCollection.document(uid).setData({
      'location': location,
      'url': url,
      'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  }
  
  // image list from snapshot
  List<GridImage> _imageListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return GridImage(
        url: doc.data['url'] ?? '',
        location: doc.data['location'] ?? '',
        timestamp: doc.data['timestamp'].toString() ?? ''
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  // get image stream
  Stream<List<GridImage>> get images {
    return imageCollection.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots().map(_imageListFromSnapshot);
  }

}
```

[duplicating a previous image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLWWz.jpg)

Comment: you have to add an index, try to cosult your terminal you will find link for the index

Comment: @Merym But how should I give the index ?. then the entire gridview has to be changed

Comment: can you show terminal error

Comment: you need to be sure to create an index for timestamp in firestore ,

Comment: @Merym There is no error in the Debug. How to create an index for timestamp ? You mean separate field for that ?

Comment: can you show you terminal

Comment: @Merym In the terminal there is nothing to show. App is launching successfully and It just only have some print statements that I coded. Please can you give me a clear explanation about that index thing ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624893/firebase-firestore-order-by-not-working

Answer (score 1):

As Meryn commented, you should use am index to solve this issue. Actually there are a lot of examples about this ([order by not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434167/firestore-query-orderby-not-working) and [firestore order by](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15928)) and in all of them it is recommended to use the index. You can follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15928#issuecomment-619352394) to do it

You would have to go to your firestore console and index the fields you are ordering by.

Go to: indexes >> Composite.

Next: add the index and wait for it to be active.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Later I found that the issue is in the pagination. Anyway I could be able to know firebase indexing is important from your answer. I could solve an future issue with that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Modify GridImage to use [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) as such

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class GridImage extends Equatable {
  final String location;
  final String url;
  final String timestamp;

  GridImage({this.location,this.url,String timestamp}):timestamp = timestamp ?? Timestamp.now().toString(); // incase timestamp is null
  

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [location,url];
}
```

Modify your _imageListFromSnapshot function as such

```
List<GridImage> _imageListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
  return GridImage(
    url: doc.data['url'] ?? '',
    location: doc.data['location'] ?? '',
    timestamp: doc.data['timestamp']?.toString() // remove null check we are already handling it inside the model and use null safe call ( ?. )
  );
}).toList().toSet().toList(); // convert the list to set to remove duplicates

}
```

Comment: Make sure to use ?. when calling toString method on timestamp

Comment: Thanks for answering. Later I found that the issue is in the pagination.