# List Data in cloud firestore using Timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to list the data in Firestore by Timestamp but it can't happening. With the `whereGreaterThan` and `OrderBy`.

```
    db.collection("Users_Photos").document(uid).collection("ImageData").whereGreaterThan("image_timestamp",1506816000).orderBy("image_timestamp").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if(e!=null)
            {

            }
         for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
         {
            if (doc.getType()==DocumentChange.Type.ADDED)
            {
                Photo photo = doc.getDocument().toObject(Photo.class);
                photosList.add(photo);
                photoListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 String name = doc.getDocument().getString("image_location");
              Log.d(TAG,name);
            }

         }

        }

    });
```

Comment: What does your data model look like? You are also only looking for documents that were recently added.

Comment: I am showing it on the Recycler view and updating in realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting your data sorted by timestamp, becasue you are not using the correct way of setting the data. As I see you are using the current time in millis instead of using server value timestamp. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027#48475027) is how you can set the timestamp correctly in Cloud Firestore. So do as explained in that post, and your data will be sorted correctly.