# How to retrieve date and time in a RecyclerView from FirebaseFirestore if i have stored time as ServerValue.TIMESTAMP in the database

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app in which user can post information and while posting I am saving the time of the post by using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in the Firestore database.

The problem is that the time is getting saved in the database as map something like this

```
time:
   .sv : "timestamp"
```

Here is a picture to my database at Firestore[image: in the rightmost column you can see how my time is getting saved in the database]

Now I want to extract human readable date and time to display to the users in a `RecyclerView`.

This is my model class through which i want to get the time but haven't included any data member yet because i don't know how to get it done.

```
public class PostDisplayModel extends TransferId{

public String teacherName;
public String topic;

PostDisplayModel(){}

public PostDisplayModel(String teacherName, String topic) {
    this.teacherName = teacherName;
    this.topic = topic;
}

public String getTeacherName() {
    return teacherName;
}

public void setTeacherName(String teacherName) {
    this.teacherName = teacherName;
}

public String getTopic() {
    return topic;
}

public void setTopic(String topic) {
    this.topic = topic;
}
}
```

Below is my Adapter Class

```
public class PostDisplayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostDisplayAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<PostDisplayModel> postsList;

PostDisplayAdapter(Context context,List<PostDisplayModel> postsList){
    this.postsList = postsList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_display_blueprint,parent,false);
    return  new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.headline.setText(postsList.get(position).getTopic());
    holder.uploaderName.setText(postsList.get(position).getTeacherName());

    final String id = postsList.get(position).id;
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,PostDisplayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",id);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postsList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    public TextView uploaderName, headline;
    public TextView time;         //this is the textview in which i want the time to get displayed

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        uploaderName = mView.findViewById(R.id.uploader_name);
        headline = mView.findViewById(R.id.headline);
        time = mView.findViewById(R.id.time);     //getting id of the time textview

    }
}
}
```

I want a correct format of that timestamp like *yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss* in textview, I am getting every other data correctly from the recycler view.

Any sort of suggestion/help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening, because you are setting the timestamp as `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. This is the right way when you are using a Firebase Realtime database. In case of Cloud Firestore, you need to set it as a **`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`**.

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)** is the correct way in which you can set the `TIMESTAMP` in a Cloud Firestore database using a model class.