# How to populate the date field only once in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

In my Cloud Firestore datababase I have a collection named `users`. Each user of my app is stored as a document within this collection. My database looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users
         |
         --- uid
              |
              --- userName: "Jane"
              |
              --- creationDate: February 28, 2018 at 1:46:00 PM UTC+2
```

In the `creationDate` property I want to store the date and time of the user when it first time joins my app. I'm using to populate this property using the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore) and it works perfectly fine.

The problem is that every time a user signs in, this property is repopulated and I want it only once, when the user joins my app for the first time.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the user exists, for example:

```
private String getUser(){
    firestore.collection("user").document("UID")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        // just fetch data
                    } else {
                        //write data
                    }
                }
            })
        //    .addOnFailureListener()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you misunderstood my problem. My property is repopulated every time I sign in. If I check for existence and the users exists, what should I do? Not to sign in?

Comment: when it does not exist: create a new user - the "date and time" method.
when it exists: use write without date and time ...  firestore. ... set(user, SetOptions.merge())