# How do i convert firebase firestore timestamp into long value?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Tried to convert `firestore` timestamp to string and I got this!

[image]

I tried `String date = FieldValue.serverTimestamp().toString();` and instead of time stamp I got this as shown in Screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eeuc.png)

Comment: The serverTimestamp is a server value so you would first have to save it and then read it back before you can convert it.

Comment: is there any way to directly access the serverTimestamp value without storing it into server? @AndréKool

Comment: As far as i know that is not possible. FieldValue.serverTimestamp() is a placeholder, its actually saying "I want firebase to replace this with the server timestamp".

Answer (score 1):

The date inside a Firestore database must be stored as a `Date` object as explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)**. Assuming that you have public getter named `getDate()` inside your model class, to print the date, please use the following code:

```
Date date = yourModelClass.getDate();
if (date != null) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US);
    String creationDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    Log.d("TAG", creationDate);
}
```

What you are actually printing there is the address of the `FieldValue` class from the memory.

Answer (score -1):

okay so the toString() will not output the date formatted since the object returned by the statement `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is a `Date` object so you can do something like this to handle date formatting.

```
Date now = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, y-M-d 'at' h:m:s a z");
Log.i("Format 1:   ", dateFormatter.format(now));
```

Comment: well the previous answer did not contain the relation to serverTimesTamp however i have edited my answer thank you for mentioning that