# Add new field or change the structure on all Firestore documents

Tags: java, android, database, google-cloud-firestore

Consider a collection of `users`. Each document in the collection has `name` and `email` as fields.

```
{
  "users": {
    "uid1": {
      "name": "Alex Saveau",
      "email": "saveau.alexandre@gmail.com"
    },
    "uid2": { ... },
    "uid3": { ... }
  }
}
```

Consider now that with this working Cloud Firestore database structure I launch my first version of a mobile application. Then, at some point I realize I want to include another field such as `last_login`.

In the code, reading all the users documents from the Firestore DB using Java would be done as

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        mUsers.add(document.toObject(User.class));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

where the class `User` contains now `name`, `email` and `last_login`.

Since the new `User` field (`last_login`) is not included in the old users stored in the DB, the application is crashing because the new `User` class is expecting a `last_login` field which is returned as `null` by the `get()` method.

What would be the best practice to include `last_login` in all the existing `User` documents of the DB without losing their data on a new version of the app? Should I run an snippet just once to do this task or are there any better approaches to the problem?

Comment: The Firebase clients typically don't crash on properties missing from the JSON. Can you share the *minimal* `User` class that is needed to reproduce the crash, as well as the full stack trace of the crash?

Comment: The crash is not actually caused by the Firebase method, it is caused because I get a `null` value. So far I have created a function to rename the key (field) name of all the documents in a collection. I will post it later.

Comment: I have added an answer. It comprises the functions I wrote to solve this issue. It's not elegant, but it works.

Comment: I have the same problem but i expect that the solution should be dealt from the server side not the client side what i think would be the best approach is to execute a script in the server side before publishing the next version and if you want to prevent exceeding the quotas i guess it's better to apply the script using paging for (n) days and when it'll be done publish the next update and so on

Answer (score 10):

You fell into a gap of NOSQL databases: Document oriented databases do not guarantee structural integrity of the data (as RDBMS do)

The deal is:

- in an *RDBMS* all stored data have the same structure at any given time (within the same instance or cluster). When changing the structure (ER-diagram) you have to *migrate* the data for all existing records which costs time and effort.

  As a result, your application can be optimized for the current version of the data structure.
- in a *Document oriented* database each record is an independent "Page" with its own independent structure. If you change the structure it only applies to *new* documents. So you don't need to migrate the existing data.

  As a result, your application must be able to deal with all versions of the data structure you've ever used in your current database.

I don't know about firebase in detail but in general you never *update* a document in a NOSQL database. You only create a new version of the document. So even if you update all documents your application must be prepared to deal with the "old" data structure...

Comment: Thanks for the information, this is useful. I have coded a small function which updates the field name of all documents in a collection. This is done in a hard-way (delete old field, write a new one) and I was expecting something more integrated with Firestore. I have not been able to find it so far.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109026/firestore-schema-versioning-and-backward-compatibility-with-android-app-to-preve but trying to see if we can do something like what protobufs have. Can we send a version info from client to firestore or something and that way Firestore can do something intelligent in terms of deciding which version to use?

Comment: @Timothy Truckle: "your application must be prepaed to deal with the "old" data structure" - do you have any suggestions/references for how you handle this for NOSQL databases? From this it sounds like each document should come with a version number that the application checks, but that seems excessive... Thanks

Comment: @smörkex Yes, a *structure version number* maintained by your application is the only way I see to come around this efficiently. Another approach would be to "try" structure versions until you find a matching one. This does not sound batter anyhow...

Comment: @b-fg please how did you go about this?? Codes?? or can it be done directly in firebase console.? or can you give code you used in adding a field to each documents in a collection. Tnks

Comment: @Ibramazin I have added an answer. It comprises the functions I wrote to solve this issue. It's not elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote some routines to help automate this process back when I posted the question. I did not post them since these are a bit rudimentary and I was hoping for an elegant Firestore-based solution. Because such solution is not still available, here are the functions I wrote.

In short, we have functions for renaming a field, adding a field, or deleting a field. To rename a field, different functions are used depending on the data type. Maybe someone could generalise this better? The functions below are:

- **add_field**: Adds a field in all documents of a collection.
- **delete_field**: Deletes a field in all documents of a collection.
- **rename_*_field**: Renames a field containing a certain data type (*) in all documents of a collection. Here I include examples for String, Integer, and Date.

**Add field**:

```
public void add_field (final String key, final Object value, final String collection_ref) {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collection_ref).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            DocumentReference docRef = document.getReference();
                            Map<String, Object> new_map = new HashMap<>();
                            new_map.put(key, value);
                            batch.update(docRef, new_map);
                        }
                        batch.commit();
                    } else {
                        // ... "Error adding field -> " + task.getException()
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // ... "Failure getting documents -> " + e
                }
            });
}
```

**Delete field**:

```
public void delete_field (final String key, final String collection_ref) {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collection_ref).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            DocumentReference docRef = document.getReference();
                            Map<String, Object> delete_field = new HashMap<>();
                            delete_field.put(key, FieldValue.delete());
                            batch.update(docRef, delete_field);
                        }
                        // Commit the batch
                        batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                // ...
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        // ... "Error updating field -> " + task.getException()
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // ... "Failure getting notices -> " + e
                }
            });
}
```

**Rename field**:

```
public void rename_string_field (final String old_key, final String new_key, final String collection_ref) {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collection_ref).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            DocumentReference docRef = document.getReference();
                            String old_value = document.getString(old_key);

                            if (old_value != null) {
                                Map<String, Object> new_map = new HashMap<>();
                                new_map.put(new_key, old_value);

                                Map<String, Object> delete_old = new HashMap<>();
                                delete_old.put(old_key, FieldValue.delete());

                                batch.update(docRef, new_map);
                                batch.update(docRef, delete_old);
                            }
                        }
                        // Commit the batch
                        batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                // ...
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        // ... "Error updating field -> " + task.getException()
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // ... "Failure getting notices ->" + e
                }
            });
}

public void rename_integer_field (final String old_key, final String new_key, final String collection_ref) {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collection_ref).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            DocumentReference docRef = document.getReference();
                            int old_value = document.getDouble(old_key).intValue();
                            Integer ov = old_value;
                            if (ov != null) {
                                Map<String, Object> new_map = new HashMap<>();
                                new_map.put(new_key, old_value);

                                Map<String, Object> delete_old = new HashMap<>();
                                delete_old.put(old_key, FieldValue.delete());

                                batch.update(docRef, new_map);
                                batch.update(docRef, delete_old);
                            }
                        }
                        // Commit the batch
                        batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                // ...
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        // ... "Error updating field -> " + task.getException()
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // ... "Failure getting notices -> " + e
                }
            });
}

public void rename_date_field (final String old_key, final String new_key, final String collection_ref) {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collection_ref).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            DocumentReference docRef = document.getReference();
                            Date old_value = document.getDate(old_key);
                            if (old_value != null) {
                                Map<String, Object> new_map = new HashMap<>();
                                new_map.put(new_key, old_value);

                                Map<String, Object> delete_old = new HashMap<>();
                                delete_old.put(old_key, FieldValue.delete());

                                batch.update(docRef, new_map);
                                batch.update(docRef, delete_old);
                            }
                        }
                        // Commit the batch
                        batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                // ...
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        // ... "Error updating field -> " + task.getException()
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // ... "Failure getting notices -> " + e
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to share because I read that you were hoping for a Firestore based solution.

This worked for me. forEach will query each document in the collection and you can manipulate as you like.

```js
    db.collection("collectionName").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(async function(doc) {
            await db.collection("collectionName").doc(doc.id).set({newField: value}, {merge: true});
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    });
```

Comment: Gold `.doc(doc.id).set({newField: value}, {merge: true});`

Comment: This answer helped me so much. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, you need to update each user to have the new property and for that I recommend you to use a `Map`. If you are using a model class when you are creating the users as explained in my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)**, to update all users, just iterate over the `users` collection amd use the following code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
userDocumentReference.set(map, SetOptions.merge());
```

Comment: @KumarSantanu You're very welcome, Kumar.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that `last_login` is a primitive data type, maybe a `long` to hold a timestamp. An auto-generated setter would look like this:

```
private long last_login;

public void setLast_login(long last_login) {
    this.last_login = last_login;
}
```

This leads to a crash when old documents that lack the field are fetched due to null assignment to a variable of a primitive data type. 
One way around it is to modify your setter to pass in a variable of the equivalent wrapper class - `Long` instead of `long` in this case, and put a null check in the setter.

```
private long last_login;

public void setLast_login(Long last_login) {
    if(last_login != null) {
        this.last_login = last_login;
    }
}
```

The cost of avoiding the null pointer exception is the boxing-unboxing overhead.