# Firestore Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to Date

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore date format

[image: FireStore Date Format]

In My fragment I get the date in this way

```
Query query = fb.collection("jobs")
                .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
 protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull JobsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull JobsLists jobsmodel) {
                holder.setDate(jobsmodel.getDate());
...
    public void setDate(Date date) {
                da =  view.findViewById(R.id.date);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String dateString = sdf.format(date);
                da.setText(dateString);
            }
```

My Job class

```
    private Date date;
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

When I insert the date in FireStore I put it this way

```
String date_val= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());  
      jobs.put("date",date_val);
```

Please help me! What should I change?

Comment: what do you get when you do this? jobsmodel.getDate()

Comment: I am supposed to get the date  @LeviAlbuquerque

Comment: what do you get instead? null?

Comment: Hey @LeviAlbuquerque I have a new question if you want to have a look at

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ServerTimestamp is allways null on Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to transform date to a format before saving, just simply pass the date object it will be saved to the database:

```
  jobs.put("date",new Date());
```

This will make it easier for firebase to parse it when trying to retrieve the data from the database.

Comment: full logcat:`                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to Date (found in field 'date')
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeym.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeym.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                 `

Comment: did you delete what you had in the database?

Comment: same prb I think ,even when I totally deleted the date field in my db ,it continued to occur,then sudenly it stopped ,maybe it needs time to update.How can I update this faster?

Comment: One more thing If you could give me some advice on how I get news from websites and display them into a fragment?