# Order Firestore data by TimeStamp in Ascending order

Tags: java, android, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing Ideas posted by the application in Firestore. The data is stored in Firestore like this **Ideas/{documentID}/IdeaObject**. The issue is when I retrieve the data it is not sorted w.r.t time it was posted. The ideas that are retrieved are in according to the id's of their documentID which is automatically create by Firestore. I have used **ServerTimestamp** in my Model Class and also when I retrieve it, I use the `orderBy` method with my Firestore reference but still nothing.

Idea.java

```
public class Idea {
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date date;
    private String title, idea, timeCommitment, ideaStage, postedBy, website, videoPitch;
    private int views, favorites;
    private ArrayList<String> lookingFor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    private String userID;
    private String timeStamp;

    public Idea() {
    }

    public Idea(String title, String idea, String timeCommitment, String ideaStage, String postedBy, String website, String videoPitch, int views, int favorites, ArrayList<String> lookingFor, ArrayList<String> tags, String userID, String timeStamp) {
        this.title = title;
        this.idea = idea;
        this.timeCommitment = timeCommitment;
        this.ideaStage = ideaStage;
        this.postedBy = postedBy;
        this.website = website;
        this.videoPitch = videoPitch;
        this.views = views;
        this.favorites = favorites;
        this.lookingFor = lookingFor;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
```

Ideas Posting Method

```
  private void postIdea() {

        final String ideaID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss");
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());


        Idea ideas = new Idea(title, idea, timeCommitment, ideaStage, AppValues.fullName, website, videoPitch, 0, 0, lookingFor, tags, AppValues.userId, "" + timestamp.getTime());

        firestoreDb.collection("ideas")
                .document(ideaID)
                .set(ideas)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        postIdeaUser(ideaID);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        hideLoadingDialog();
                        showToast(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Retrieving all Ideas by Time

```
   firestoreDb.collection("ideas")
                .orderBy("timeStamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            ideaArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                            ideaArrayList.clear();

                            for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                                Idea idea = documentSnapshot.toObject(Idea.class);
                                if (!idea.getUserID().equals(AppValues.userId)) {
                                    ideaArrayList.add(idea);
                                }
                            }

                            callAdapter();

                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
                            errorText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

What I want to achieve is retrieve all the ideas and have them ordered ascending by the TimeStamp value.

Comment: Why are you storing both a field called `date` annotated with `@ServerTimestamp` and a formatted `timeStamp` string?  Seems like you would just want the `@ServerTimestamp` value, and make your queries use that.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you please specify how can I use the serverTimestamp value in query? I tried using this when I retrieve the

     data.orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING) but still nothing.

Comment: I'd expect that to work.

Comment: What does "nothing" mean? Does `task.getException()` return something?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You cannot use a String (`timeStamp`) when querying your database instead of a Date (`date`) and expect to behave as it was a date. So to solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
firestoreDb.collection("ideas")
            .orderBy("timeStamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

to

```
firestoreDb.collection("ideas")
            .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

To make it work, this kind of query requires an index. To create one, please check my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore whereEqualTo, orderBy and limit(1) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)

Comment: I am using long type timestamp still not getting desired result.

Comment: @AnkitMishra You need to use a [Firestore Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027), not a long value.

Comment: Well, I am using Epoch Timestamp of type number. So think it like a  number and I want to sort according to that number. if number is bigger it should come first.

Comment: @AnkitMishra Without seeing your code and database schema, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: can you please check twitter DM?

Comment: I just created index and its working perfectly fine with timestamp as I wanted.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would love. But it would be awesome if you give a reference to my answer for this post.. I have wrote answer too.. here it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/70045716/13272795   . It helped me a lot I want other find it helpful too. So please consider putting my answer link to the your answer. and yes I already did up voted.

Comment: That index issue has already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working).

Comment: It would be helpful if you add mine answer or the answer you told in comment in your accepted answer.  I think it would helpful a lot.

Comment: Btw I must say you rocks in firebase thing.

Comment: @AnkitMishra Yes, you're right. I just edited my answer.

Comment: Btw can you suggest me something on smart searching algorithm. I want to search something like I do in mysql. But unfortunately firebase has very limited searching capabilities.

Comment: @AnkitMishra Maybe this [approach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) would help.

Answer (score 16):

In my case, the vanilla version would be,

```
firestoreDb.collection("ideas")
     .orderBy("timestamp", "asc")

firestoreDb.collection("ideas")
     .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
```

"ideas" is the name of your collection

"timestamp" is the key or field or column name to be used for sorting.

"asc" or "desc" is the option to be used for the order

Answer (score 1):

You have to also add index in your firebase account which is in database -> Indexes -> add index

Comment: You mean not in the code?

Answer (score 1):

you just have to change the data type of your timestamp to Timestamp

```
--- import com.google.firebase.Timestamp
```

(in kotlin)

```
val timeStamp : Timestamp = Timestamp.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create index and it will start working with timestamp too. Just make sure timestamp is a number type and not a string.

To create index best way is to search `FAILED_PRECONDITION:` in Android Studio logcat and you will see a link just follow that link and create index.
 Example : `FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...`

Feel free to ask any query.

Comment: What do you mean to create an index? Also, how do you implement that index?

Comment: I mean database index.

Comment: Is that done in the kotlin code?

Answer (score 0):

You can order your firebase data on the console, following these steps.

**Step 1:** Click on those three lines on your documents collection.

[image]

**Step 2:** From there, you get the field that you want to filter by. You enter whichever field that is, in my case it is "timestamp".

[image]

**Step 3:** Select the Sort Results you want to apply, for my case it is "asc", and then you click apply, and it should order what you want in the database.