# Set start position in my RecyclerView when using FirestorePagingAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm using Firestore as a database and `RecyclerView` combined with `FirestorePagingAdapter` to present data in my Android app.

Data presented is sorted by date and I'd like to set default start position for `RecyclerView` to show a recent object. Currently, by default it shows the first one, which in my case is the oldest one. This is problematic for a long list, as user has to scroll down for a long time.

Is it possible to somehow override this behavior?

**EDIT 1:**
I already sort data by date, but I'd like to start from objects in the middle (e.g. from the current month) and have ability to scroll backward and forward. For example imagine list of movies - you want to see recent ones and have ability to scroll to older and newer ones.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You have three ways in which you can achieve this. The first one would be to add a **[date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)** to your items and then query the database according to it. To achieve this, you should use a query that looks like the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = collection("items").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

You can pass as the second argument the direction, which can be `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING`, according to your needs.

The second approach would be to reverse the order of your `RecyclerView` using the following lines of code:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

And the third approach would be to verride the `getItem()` method to invert the item lookup like this:

```
@Override
public HashMap getItem(int pos) {
    return super.getItem(getCount() - 1 - pos);
}
```

One more thing to note, the `FirestorePagingAdapter` in the `FirebaseUI` library is designed to **get** data, not to listen for realtime updates.

Comment: Is there everything alright, have you solved the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I already have the date field and I'm sorting by it. But my problems is the following - even though I have objects spanning from 1 year ago to 1 year in the future, I'd like to always start with current ones (let's say from the current month). This would mean user can scroll back and forward.

Comment: This is basically another question. Don't edit a question by adding another question, just post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. My personal hint is to use a query with ranges.

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you for the initial question, please consider accepting it. Thanks!