# Firestore FieldValue.ServerTimestamp always null while using model class in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hhis may be asked many times but none of the solutions didn't works for me now let me tell you what I have tried so far am using just simple model class to save values in Cloud Firestore db and in that model class am having using timestamp field but while inserting my timestamp is always null don't know where am making mistake now let me post my code :

```
 import com.google.firebase.firestore.ServerTimestamp;

    import java.util.Date;

      public class DriverMasterModel {

    private String test;
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date date;

    public DriverMasterModel() {}

    public DriverMasterModel(String test) { this.test = test; }

    public String getTest() { return test; }
    @PropertyName("Created_At")
    public Date getDate() { return date; }
}
```

and here am inserting the data to db:

```
DriverMasterModel driverMasterModel=new DriverMasterModel();
                driverMasterModel.setTest("test");
                FirebaseFirestore dbb=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                dbb.collection("Test").add(driverMasterModel).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

                    }
                });
```

But my Created_at field always null in Firestore db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting always `null` because your model class is wrong. Your `MasterModel` class should look like this:

```
public class MasterModel {
    private String test;
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date date;

    public MasterModel() {}

    public MasterModel(String test) { this.test = test; }

    public String getTest() { return test; }

    public Date getDate() { return date; }
}
```

See, the name of the class is the same as the name of the constructor and the name of the `Date` object is simple `date` and not `Created_At`.

**Edit:** According to your comment, please see the new configuration of your model class:

```
public class MasterModel {
    private String test;
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date createdAt, updatedAt;

    public MasterModel() {}

    public MasterModel(String test) { this.test = test; }

    public String getTest() { return test; }

    public Date getCreatedAt() { return createdAt; }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() { return updatedAt; }
}
```

Comment: sorry bro am using constructor with same name only i missed that while posting the code ,  and my another question is my fieldName of that  timestamp is Created_At then how can i change the name to date

Comment: i need that fieldname as Created_At how to save it in that name

Comment: Try to use the exact model class I have posted. But remember, delete the records you have now in the database and add fresh data. Does it work this way?

Comment: still no luck bro :(

Comment: Should work, I have personally test it. Do you have an error or what?

Comment: its working sir but saving it in db as date but i need to save it as Created_At so can i rename it

Comment: It will not work either if you keep it in this way. When you are using a getter that looks like this: `getCreated_At()`, Firebase is looking after a field that is named `created_At` and **not** `Created_At`. See the lower case `c` and the capital letter `C`? To solve all this problems, simply name the `Date` object as **date** as in my answer and your problem will be solved.

Comment: its like i need to maintain two timestamp one is created_at and another one is updated_at the how to do this

Comment: I'll modify you the model class now.

Comment: il and try and let you know now

Comment: Ok. Keep me posted.

Comment: you are the champ @alexmamo

Comment: thank you so much @alex but one doubt i need to save it like Created_At how to name the variable name

Comment: `how to name the variable name?` As in the second part of my answer, `createdAt` and `updatedAt`. Don't name it `Created_At`, it will not work.

Comment: it works @alex i have used propername annotation to make it works thanks and your shopping task was really helpful to understand the firestore concepts keep doing it