# Date based query from Firebase realtime database when the date is saved as a String

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to run a date based query from a Firebase database if the date is saved as a String? Or can it be converted? I want to be able to search for records within a particular date range but the dates are saved and retrieved as strings. I use a `DatePickerDiaglog` to set the date when I add the record. The following is the method for adding a record:

```
private void addAnimal(){
        String breed = editTextBreed.getText().toString().trim();
        String gender = spinnerGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String source = editTextSource.getText().toString().trim();
        String DOB = mDisplayDate.getText().toString().trim();
        String tag = editTextTagNumber.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(breed)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You should enter a breed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(source)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You should enter a source", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(DOB)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You should enter a Date of Birth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(tag)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You should enter a Tag Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (tag.length() < 6){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter valid tag number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else{
            String id = databaseAnimal.push().getKey();

            Animal animal = new Animal(id, breed, gender, source, DOB, tag);

            databaseAnimal.child(id).setValue(animal);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Animal added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } }
```

This is the code I used to retrieve all the records.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_retrieved);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_item);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("animals");
        animalList = new ArrayList<>();


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String tempListValue =(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                //String tempListValue = animalList.get(position).toString();
                        //.get(position).toString();

                TextView animalID = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.animalID);
                String animalIDText = (String) animalID.getText();

                TextView animalGender = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.gender);
                String animalGenderText = (String) animalGender.getText();


                TextView animalDOB = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.DOB);
                String animalDOBText = (String) animalDOB.getText();

                TextView source = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.source);
                String sourceText = (String) source.getText();

                TextView animalBreed = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.breed);
                String animalBreedText = (String) animalBreed.getText();

                TextView animalTag = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.tag);
                String animalTagText = (String) animalTag.getText();

                //Multiple Values
                Intent intent = new Intent(DataRetrieved.this, ViewAnimalDetails.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("EXTRA_ID",animalIDText);
                extras.putString("EXTRA_DOB",animalDOBText);
                extras.putString("EXTRA_GENDER",animalGenderText);
                extras.putString("EXTRA_SOURCE",sourceText);
                extras.putString("EXTRA_BREED", animalBreedText);
                extras.putString("EXTRA_TAG", animalTagText);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);

                //intent.putExtra("ListViewClickedValue", tempListValue);

                startActivity(intent);


            }
        }); //List view item click ends
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot animalSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Animal animal = animalSnapshot.getValue(Animal.class);
                    animalList.add(animal);
                }

                AnimalInfoAdapter animalInfoAdapter = new AnimalInfoAdapter(DataRetrieved.this, animalList);
                listView.setAdapter(animalInfoAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Let me know if there is any other information needed, Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to use date object for DOB, consider saving the date-string in such format as  `YYYYMMddHHmmSSS` so that it will be easy for you to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to run a date based query from a Firebase database if the date is saved as a string?

The simple answer is yes, you can query based on a String but the results will be wrong. The results that you get when you query literal strings is totally different than the result you get when querying based on `Date` objects.

> Or can it be converted?

Yes it can but the result will be the same as above. The simplest solution to solve this, is to convert the *date* property from `String` to `Date` and query the data according to it.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? Is it being converted before it's saved or upon its retrieval?

Comment: It is saved as a Date object in the first place. Take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)**.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help