# How to query last 7 days' data from Firestore Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query Cloud Firestore data in last 7 days. I am using server timestamp of Firestore also storing the time in millis.

```
CollectionReference IOTransactions = db.collection(userID)
                .document("userData").collection("StockTransactions");

        Query transactionsQuery = IOTransactions.orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        transactionsQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w("FirestoreDemo", "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    if (doc.get("timestamp") != null)
                        transactionsList.add(doc.toObject(StockTransaction.class));
                    Log.d("Firestore", "Added item");
                }

                if(transactionsList.size() < 1 )
                    emptyTransactionsPage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.d("Firestore Reading", "Successfully fetched");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        });
```

How can I query the data created in last 7 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using server timestamp of Firestore also storing the time in milliseconds.

So if you are storing the timestamp in milliseconds, you are doing it wrong.

> How can I query the data created in last 7 days.

To be able to query your database according to a periode of time, your timestamp property should be o type `Date` and **not** long. To see how you can achieve this, please take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)**.

Once you have the property set correctly, a query that looks like this should do the trick:

```
IOTransactions.whereLessThan("timestamp", now).whereGreaterThan("timestamp", sevenDayAgo);
```

In which `now` and `sevenDayAgo` are two `Date` objects representing the present time and a moment in time seven days ago.

Comment: I guess I couldn't tell right that servertimestamp is in date format but I also store as millis in another field. Thank you for your answer it works for my situation. I have tried before with little differencies so it didn't work but this works well.

Comment: Alex, can you help me here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124994/how-to-fetch-documents-from-one-month-old-only-firestore/61125159#61125159

Comment: @Alex Mamo Can you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927499/how-to-use-pagination-to-firestore-query-using-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

According to My Knowledge you can also use the following query to get the result

```
Query query = mdb.collection("$YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME").orderBy("$YOUR_FIELD")
               .whereGreaterThan("$YOUR_FIELD",$Begin_Date_Object)
               .endAt($YOUR_DATE_OBJECT);
```

**Note:** You need to declare a **Java.Util.Date** object to endAt field and
orderBy must be always before startAt() or endAt() method.

The end at searches all documents containing the end at value of field in orderBy