# how to fetch documents from one month old only firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a query to fetch only 1 month old documents.

I store the creation time of the document itself

```
timestamp : 9 Apr, 2020 10:03:43 AM
```

Now, in my query , I want to get all the documents whithin the current month but I dont want to use currentDate from my client (so it cannot be changed) but also I dont want to query that document to find the timestamps of that document

Query

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("orders").whereEqualTo("shopId",shopId)
                .whereEqualTo("status", 7).startAt().endAt().get().await()
```

I want to know an efficient server aproximation to set at `.startAt().endAt()` to query just the documents with status 7 in which has past 1 month

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore does not offer timeboxed queries that restrict a range of documents based on the sense of server time.  You will have to trust that the client is sending the correct time.

The only control you have over time is using [request.time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) in security rules.  You could write a rule to allow queries that only fall within times based on the server timestamp, but it's still up to the client to specify the time correctly in the query.  The rules will not be able to filter results based on time.

You might want to read more about how server timestamps work with security rules at the end of [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestores-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b).

Comment: Thanks a lot Doug! this can bring some security issues in my app, since I need to know from the client that the current date is actually right to let them pay a bill, if they change the current time I will be losing sells

Comment: There is one thing about the token you mentioned in your article, why does not firebase stores that token with the current time that the user has sent the petition and not jsut genereate the time when that petition hits the server ? does that fixs the problem of having another later time than the one we just sent ? About the Leap, is that necessary if we can get the time from the current post request ?

Comment: Doug, can you help me a little bit more on this ? I really need to do this timebox query, is anyway posbile to aproximate this ?

Comment: I can't help you any more than what I've written in that article.

Comment: I know doug but I know you can guide me to the answer, but actually I would love to have any aproximation to the issue than use the rules