# I'm trying to filter firestore content on basis on of a date picked by user. Say Display all data for 14th Feb

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the user to pick a date and then on click of a button will display all the content from Firestore related to that data.

Here `mDisplayDate` is a `DatePicker` Dialog and I want to display the data. I've done the display part but `whereEqualTo()` takes two hard coded strings as field and value.

```
noteBookref.whereEqualTo("Date" , mDisplayDate.toString()).orderBy("Date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get();
```

[The Database looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dQKg.png)

Comment: And what's the question? Please also add your database structure.

Comment: Database structure looks like this,

Date:14th Feb
Model:Phone Model1
Issue:Abc

Date:16th Feb
Model:PhoneModel2
Issue xyz

Here the user will pick a date using DatePicker Dialog , say he picks 16th Feb then I want to display the content dated under 16th. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dQKg.png

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to filter firestore content on basis on of a date picked by user. Say Display all data for 14th Feb

You are storing the `Date` property as a String you are doing it wrong.

To be able to query your database according to a specific date, your `Date` property should be o type `Date` and **not** String. To see how you can achieve this, please take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)**.

Once you have the property set correctly, a query like this should do the trick:

```
noteBookref.whereEqualTo("Date" , date).orderBy("Date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get();
```

In which `date` is a `Date` object representing the date you are looking for. Remember to delete the existing data and add fresh one.