# update null field to map Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have such Object:

```
data class Task(var id: Int? = null,
 var cabinId: Int = 0,
 var startTime: DateTime,
 var endTime: DateTime? = null
)
```

when I write document it is totaly okey:

```
    db.collection("games").document(game.idForTitle)
        .set(game)
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: ${documentReference}")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e)
        }
```

but when I try to update the endTime field it throws:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: org.joda.time.DateTime (found in field endTime)

The intersting thing is that startTime filed is writen as map, but endTime is null type.

Anyone knows what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The interesting thing is that startTime field is written as map, but endTime is null type.

The `endTime` is `null` because it's initialized in the constructor to be `null`.

```
var endTime: DateTime? = null
```

If you need the sever timestamp, change the type of the field to be of type [Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date), use an annotation and leave the field uninitialized as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [ServerTimestamp is always null on Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-always-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)

If you need to update a field, make sure that the type of that field is one of the [supported data types in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).