# How do I cast FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to Kotlin/Java Date Class

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save the date that a post was created in Firestore but I do not want to use the System time. Rather I want to use the server timestamp for accuracy sake. So I am using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to get the server timestamp but the data type of my variable that holds this is Date. So How can I cast `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to `Date`?

Below is how my data class looks

```
data class MyModel( var timeStamp: Date,
    constructor(): this(Calendar.getInstance().time, "")
}
```

PS: When I declare the timestamp as FieldValue in the data class, I get the error below:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue

Because `FieldValue` is not a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). You should use the [Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date) class or any other class that extends `Date` class, for example [Timestamp](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class.

> How do I cast FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to Kotlin/Java Date Class

There is no need to do any cast. In Java there is even **no** need to initialize the `timeStamp` field. To make it work, you should only use an annotation, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [ServerTimestamp is always null on Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-always-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027#48475027)

**Edit:**

In Kotlin, you should initialize your `timeStamp` field in the constructor with a `null` value like this:

```
data class MyModel(
               @ServerTimestamp
               val timeStamp: Date? = null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. I have 2 follow up questions
1. You said I don't have to initialize Date. If so, then how will my contractor look. Sample code in Kotlin, please?
2. What is the best way to get the current time when you want to save a post in Firestore. To avoid using client time which may be wrong,  I used FieldValue.serverTimestamp(). Do you have a better approach?

Comment: Hi calistus! For the first question, please see my updated answer. Regarding the second, no, there is not a better approach.

Comment: @AlexMamo what if I want to implement it in an already running Firebase project where earlier, I had a field `createdAt: String` and now to sync the data for all the Timezones I prefer to use the `ServerTimestamp`. So, how can I update this while being able to use the previous Data?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of an object to hold this value and later while using this value check the type of the object and make use of it. As of my knowledge the datatype returned is Long and you have to convert it manually to Data if you need.

The code for this will look like this,

replace this

```
data class MyModel( var timeStamp: Date,
```

with

```
data class MyModel( var timeStamp: Object,
```

And when using this `timeStamp` anywhere check it's type. 
In java it will look like

```
if (timeStamp instanceof Long) {
    // change Long to Date
    //do this
}else{
    //do something else
}
```

set the value for `timeStamp` as `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` itself.

Answer (score 0):

model class

```
data class MyModel(
        @get: PropertyName("timestamp") @set: PropertyName("timestamp") var timestamp: Date= Date()
    )
```

when initialize it;

```
val model = MyModel().apply{
   this.timestamp to FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}
```