# Cannot update an array in Firestore due an error

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have this data class in Kotlin:

```
data class Product(
    var id: String? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    @ServerTimestamp
    var createdAt: Date? = null
): Serializable
```

And this Firestore database:

```
Root
 \
 carts <- collection
   \
   cartId <- document
     \
     products: [productObj, productObj, productObj]
```

And I'm trying to add another `Product` object to the list. I'm using this line:

```
cartsRef.document(cartId).update("products", FieldValue.arrayUnion(product)).addOnCompleteListener {}
```

And I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. FieldValue.serverTimestamp() can only be used with set() and update()

Why do I get this error since I am using `update()` function?

Comment: To save timestamp to firebase, date should be of type Map.

Comment: @Walid Just tried to change the `product` object to a Map, and I get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I meant the date field should be Map<String, Object>

Comment: It might simply be the case that `@ServerTimestamp` does not work with objects passed to `FieldValue.arrayUnion()`.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks but is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In your Data class you should try changing the `@ServerTimestamp` to

```
@ServerTimestamp private val serverTimestamp:Date
```

Comment: What else have you tried? There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534290) that may also be of help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ServerTimestamp private val yourDate: Date? = null
```

Key points are that it has to be `private` and nullable with default value `null`, or if not default, set `null` in `constructor`