# Firestore Ignore null value in object

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It would be perfect, if there was @IgnoreIfNull annotation for normalizing my db, But there is not so How should I handle if my data has null value in object class?

```
      public class Word {

               public String id;
               public String wordName;
               @IgnoreNull        //Origin may be null
               public String wordOrigin;
              }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add the data as a `Map` and **not** as an object. In this way, you have more control over what properties you want to add. If you have properties with `null` values, simply don't add them to the `Map`.

This is available in Cloud Firestore. In the Firebase Realtime Database, there is no way you can have keys that can hold `null` values.

Comment: this won't work if you are using the @ServerTimestamp which should be null

Comment: @YanayHollander Hey Yanay! The ServerTimestamp should be `null` **only** when you are using a POJO class. In the case of a Map, you cannot pass `null` and expect a field to be populated with the ServerTimestamp. Please check my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-always-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027#48475027)**.