# How to sequential order number with Firestore and Google Cloud?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an order system on Google Cloud using Firestore. I have one Firestore database and multiple servers handling orders by location. Each branch starts daily orders from 1, resetting each day.

How can I set up sequential order numbers using Firestore and Google Cloud? Any code examples or tips? Implementation should always be sequential and without gaps.

Note: Order number is needed and will be saved in other collections in addition to orders collection

Answer (score 1):

The limitation regarding sequential IDs refers to [document IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids). If you want to store the order number as a numeric field inside a document, you can go ahead with that, but please note that such a solution is not practical at all. Why? It's because in order to increment the order number you have to read the last order number first before writing the new one. So instead of paying only for write operation in Firestore, you'll have to pay a read + a write.

In my opinion, the best option that you have is to store a Firestore timestamp field that has the [precision of nanoseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543643/5246885) inside each order. That means that you can order the orders according to that field and achieve the same result. That also means that you don't have to check the order number or use any transactions.

**Edit:**

If you really need that sequential order number, then I recommend you store it in [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) in a schema that looks like this:

```
db
|
--- orderNumber: 25
```

To increment the order number, you can simply use [increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments), which is an atomic operation. To reset the timer, you can use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/), which allows you to [schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767485/is-it-not-possible-to-have-a-code-in-the-background-who-will-be-called-every-24h/54767571#54767571) the update of the order number to zero.

In such a case, there is nothing to pay since the write operation in the Realtime Database is free of charge, while when you read you'll only pay for reading a number, which represents an incredibly small amount of bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. But how do I assign numbers to orders? A restaurant needs to see the number of the order. This same number needs to be saved in other collections as well. I understand that with timestamps sorting will be guaranteed

Comment: In that case, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll set some time to work on this soon and see if it works well.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: Any updates? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hey! Sadly other work got prioritized over this, so I haven't got a chance to try it out yet. But I appreciate your help so far

Comment: Keep me posted when you'll have the time to try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using sequential ID's is not recommended for Firestore there is a post about this topic and some suggestions: [Firestore generated key versus custom key in a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024150/firestore-generated-key-versus-custom-key-in-a-collection/51026105#51026105)

Comment: I meant an order number that is separate from document id.

Comment: Say a field called order_number of type number

Comment: It is common to have order_number but don't expect them to be truly sequential, if there are multiple orders coming at the same type, you can use transactions with firebase real-time to ensure integrity another way common use should be a SQL db.

Comment: Are you sure transactions can handle the case of orders placed at the same from multiple users? Say maybe 30 orders/s ?

Comment: And by "firebase real-time" did you mean rtdb? instead of firestore?

Comment: Yes, rtdb, and that is the idea behind the transactions, there is some documentation regarding that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore