# Manipulate value stored in Firebase document field before applying order by

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firebase Firestore, I have a large number of documents in a collection, each of which has a field called `bookTime`, which stores a date in String format. The format is `dd MM yyyy HH`, so we can't sort it in descending order to get a meaningful list with the latest document on top. The format we need for it to work properly is `yyyy MM dd HH`. This is my query:

`mQuery = mQuery.orderBy("bookTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);`

What change should I make so I can actually get a list with the document having the newest `bookTime` on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What change should I make so I can actually get a list with the document having newest bookTime on top?

First of all, don't use Strings to store dates. It's recommended to use [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects. The `Date` is a [Firestore supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

For more information on how to store a Date, please see my answer from the following post:

- [ServerTimestamp is always null on Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)

Once you store the Date correctly, that query will work perfectly fine.

---

However, if you insist to store the dates and times as Strings, the option that you have is to store them in a format that can be sorted lexicographical and chronological at the same time.

The ISO 8601 format looks like this:

```
20200329T184525
```

That's the current time I'm answering this question.

```
March 29, 2020 6:45:25 PM UTC
```