# Sort after retrieving data from Firestore but before populating recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Problem:

I am storing events (think calendar events) in Firestore and the times as Strings because timestamps in Firestore seem to be something else. Ex. 10:00 AM, 10:00 PM, etc. I want to display these events in my `RecyclerView` sorted by time.

Is it possible to sort them before populating the `RecyclerView`? I tried looking and found nothing online and don't know how to approach this problem.

I am using FirebaseUI and I'm guessing this has to happen in the Adapter somewhere

```
Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection(year).whereIn("location", "Park").orderBy("time", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
                    //Recycler options
                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions < EventModel > options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder < EventModel > ()
                            .setQuery(query, EventModel.class)
                            .build();

                    eventAdapter = new EventAdapter(options);
                    mFirestoreList.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
                    eventAdapter.startListening();
                    eventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: You can use `Date` data type to store dates. `FirebaseFirestore` supports query and operations on `Date` field.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get accurate results when querying a Firestore database, you should use either a java [Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date) or a Firestore [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) object, but definitely **not** a String. I'm saying that, because the way String objects are ordered, is [lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) and the result that you'll get will not be much of a help.

To be able to add a Timestamp value, you can use the solution from my following answer:

> [ServerTimestamp is always null on Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-always-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027#48475027)

The query that you are actually using should not be changed, it will work the way it is right now.