# Can't instantiate abstract class java.util.Calendar in Android Studio with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, calendar

My application tries to list a POJO object but when debugging, I get the error:

> Can't instantiate abstract class java.util.Calendar

Is it possible that Firebase does not work correctly with CRUDs with Calendar type variables?

The pojo class Contain:

```
private String idParcela;
private String nombreParcela;
private int hectareas;
private Calendar ultimoTratamienetoQuimico;
private Calendar proximoTratamientoQuimico;
private String fruta;
private String variedad;
private String nombreTratamiento;
private int diasTratarQuimicamente;
```

And getters,setters, builders etc.

```
private void listarDatos() {
        databaseReference.child("parcelas").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listaParcelas.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot objSnaptshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Parcela p = objSnaptshot.getValue(Parcela.class);
                    listaParcelas.add(p);
                    arrayAdapterParcela = new ArrayAdapter<Parcela>(listaParcelas.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listaParcelas);
                    listvListaParcela.setAdapter(arrayAdapterParcela);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that Firebase does not work correctly with CRUDs with Calendar type variables?

The [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class from "java.util" package, isn't a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). So there is no way in which Firebase can serialize such an object. However, if you need to work with dates, you can use [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object or a Firestore Timestamp object:

> When stored in Cloud Firestore, precise only to microseconds; any additional precision is rounded down.

Please see below how you can achieve that:

> [ServerTimestamp is always null on Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)

Comment: I have modified the properties of the POJOto Date, and I have added this and it works! Date LastTreatmentDate = LastTreatmentDateCalendar.getTime ();
                            Date NextTreatmentDate = NextTreatmentDateCalendar.getTime ();