# Get documents of last 24 hours from Firestore in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get documents of the last 24 hours from Firestore in my Android app. In my case, documents are post holders. Every post document has a field that holds Firestore Timestamp. Is there a way to compare timestamp to date in a query? I will use device date to compare to timestamp. What if the device date is not correct at the time?

My Firestore looks like:

```
  --- posts (collection)                                                     
   |     |
   |     --- postid (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- country_code: "TR"
   |          |
   |          --- timestamp: Firestore.Timestamp
   |          |
   |          --- post_text: "Some Text" 
   |          |
   |          --- username: "username"
```

Comment: Can you share more details about how you document looks like and if you are already storing a timestamp field in it ? Are you using Java or Kotlin?

Comment: I edited the question. I use Java for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to compare timestamp to date in a query? I will use device date to compare to timestamp.

It certainly is. The simplest way to solve this would be to get the User's date as an object of type [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and perform a query that looks like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference postsRef = rootRef.collection("posts");
Query queryByTimestamp = postsRef.whereGreaterThan("timestamp", yourDateObject - 24h);
queryByTimestamp.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

What I see in your screenshot:

```
timestamp: "Server.Timestamp"
```

It Will definitely not work. The timestamp property should contain a Date or a Firestore timestamp as explained in my answer from the following post:

> [How to add a Timestamp in Firestore with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)

So never add the `Server.Timestamp` as a String.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Alex . But what if user device date is incorrectly configured?  I will use this query to create feed.

Comment: In that case, you might also consider writing a document with a timestamp, read its value, and then perform the query. That's an alternative solution.