# Storing application start and end time in GCP Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In one of my projects, I want to store application start time and end time to GCP Firestore in timestamp format.

I have tried the following things

1. I tried to save the java DateTime but in the Firestore its storing
   as array(Firestore screenshot).[image]
2. and also I tried to use the FieldValue but it's storing start time and end time as the same.
   [image]

is there any way I can store time stamp in GCP Firestore with the actual time difference(application start time and end time)

I am storing the below model class by updating the completeAt and startedAt fields(note: I have tried with type FieldValue as well instead of Date).

```
public class Test{
 private Date completeAt
private Date completeAt
}
```

Comment: Please share your attempts in code, to see it more clearly. Please also add a screenshot of your result in Firestore.

Comment: updated my question with screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first attempt, `completeAt` it's not an array, it's an object.

Regarding your second attempt:

> Is there any way I can store time stamp in GCP Firestore with the actual time difference(application start time and end time)

Both fields `completeAt` and `startedAt` are populated with the [correct data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027). However, the values are not correct. If you want the `startedAt` field to hold a Timestamp value when the app starts, then you should perform an [update operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) right then. As soon as the user stops using the app, perform another update the add the corresponding Timestamp to the `completeAt` field. In this way, you'll have different values for each field.