# How to get server time firebase Firestore kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I searched the documentation, Googled, and similar questions, but could not find a clear solution on how to get the server time, I need it to record the time of sending messages to Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the server time?

To be able to read a timestamp, you have to write it first and then read it back. This can be done using [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#serverTimestamp()). In Java, you can simply do it using the solution from the following answer:

- [How to add a Timestamp in Firestore with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/how-to-add-a-timestamp-in-firestore-with-android/48475027#48475027)

But it can simply be translated into Kotlin too.

Please also note that the Firebase server generates the timestamp. This is not generated on the client, but on the server.

Comment: Hey Danil. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes I created new questions

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Yes he helped me further develop the solution to the problem, but globally it remains unsolved